# Use of Autofac in a greenfield ASP.Net core project

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac

Can't find the answer anywhere. The question is : what would be the added value of using Autofac in a new ASP.Net Core project.

The [documentation of Autofac states](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#dependency-injection-hooks) :

> Unlike ASP.NET classic integration, ASP.NET Core is designed
>   specifically with dependency injection in mind. What that means is if
>   you’re trying to figure out, say, how to inject services into MVC
>   views that’s now controlled by (and documented by) ASP.NET Core -
>   there’s not anything Autofac-specific you need to do other than set up
>   your service provider as outlined above.

All documentation on ASP.net core and Autofac seems to be related with hooking up existing Autofac injections in an upgrade to ASP.net core.

Does that mean that Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection takes over the role of Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection , or ..  in case there is a distinctive role to play for Autofac and what would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You replace the built-in DI of ASP.NET Core if you need features that it doesn't offer.

If you're not missing any features that Autofac offers over the built-in DI, there's no reason to switch.

See [MSDN Blogs: Comparing ASP.NET Core IoC container service lifetimes with Autofac IoC container instance scopes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/01/26/comparing-asp-net-core-ioc-service-life-times-and-autofac-ioc-instance-scopes/) for a comparison of features for which you might want to use Autofac:

- InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope()
- InstancePerOwned()
- Thread Scope (based on lifetime scopes)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You meant with : 'there's no reason to switch'... to Autofac, I guess?

Comment: @CoffeCold yes.